# Mobile module for OpenERP

Tags: odoo

I want build a mobile module for OpenERP. Anybody can tell how to make a mobile module for OpenERP?

Comment: Do you mean you want to modify the web interface for mobile devices? More details will get you a better answer.

Comment: I mean i want to build a module which export xml data?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your reply. If you include @Don in your comment, then it will notify me. I don't understand what exporting XML data has to do with the word mobile. Are you talking about building something that will run on a smart phone, or something else?

Comment: @Don Kirkby : I want to create an OpenERP mobile client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like someone else is also working on [a mobile client for OpenERP](http://openerpclientmobile.blogspot.com/). Is that what you're asking about?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile version of OpenERP Web Client will be released very soon, currently it is under development!

Comment: This's a interesting news. I'm waiting :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that OpenERP is working on a mobile client to be released in v6.1. Check https://code.launchpad.net/~openerp-dev/openerp-web/mobile-client

Answer (score 0):

In OE 6.1 Mobile Client is Embedded in web itself just add //mobile at the end of the your web url e.g. `http://localhost:8069/mobile` and you will be access it over mobile device, but feature is in beta mode so it is in read only mode only. And any Standard OD module can be access on mobile client their is no need to have any separate coding for the same.

Regards